# Why the counting of the days change when the for-loop is nested within a for-loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

This is a problem from Python for Everybody, exercise 9.2

My question is why the counting of the days change when the for-loop is nested within a for-loop?

This is my code that provides the correct answer: `{'Sat': 1, 'Fri': 20, 'Thu': 6}`

```
file_name = input("Enter a file name: ")

file_handle = open(file_name)

day_count_list = []

day_count_dict = dict()

for line in file_handle:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        line = line.split()
        day_counts = line[2]
        day_count_list.append(day_counts)
        
for day in day_count_list:
    day_count_dict[day] = day_count_dict.get(day, 0) + 1

print(day_count_dict)
```

However, when the for-loop is nested, the answer becomes: `{'Sat': 27, 'Fri': 330, 'Thu': 21}`

```
for line in file_handle:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        line = line.split()
        day_counts = line[2]
        day_count_list.append(day_counts)
        for day in day_count_list:
            day_count_dict[day] = day_count_dict.get(day, 0) + 1
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Use a debugger to step through the execution and see how each line changes the state of the program. For better answers, include the file your program is reading in your question. As of now we have no idea what it's counting.

Comment: Because you add up a Sat from the first iteration of the outer loop again in each subsequent iteration of the outer loop. If you want nested loop you should clear the day_count_list for each iteration of the outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code, the inner `for` loop will run all the way through for every iteration of the outer loop. That means the body of the inner loop will run *many* times.

This is different than the behavior of the first code, where the second for loop will run *once* after the first loop has run once.